# Injecting data into a view in chrome custom tab and reading some data in custom tab from app

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

1. Can I inject some text in chrome custom tab, other than title bar? Say in signup page, can I fill data by injecting data from the app?
2. Also, can I read data present in custom tab from my app?

Comment: Do you own both the app and the web content?

Comment: No, I only own app.

Comment: I have same question, however I do own both my app and my webapp. How does it make a difference ?

Comment: If you own the web content, you can make it respond to data sent by the app through URL parameters, then use the data to fill out the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I inject Javascript code into Chrome Custom Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732496/can-i-inject-javascript-code-into-chrome-custom-tabs)